# Estimation of rows after nested loop higher than product of the two inputs

Tags: postgresql

Please see query plan below. The estimate for number of rows coming out of the outer nested loop is 23.690.271. The estimation for rows coming out of the driving element of the outer nested loop (the inner nested loop) is 262 rows. The estimation of rows for the probing element of the nested loop (the index scan using idx_tab3_1_p45) is 100 rows.

Please explain to me how postgres thinks that over 23mio rows come out of the nested loop when the maximum that can come out as per its own estimations is 262*100 = 26.200 (when for each element of the driving table all 100 elements of the probing table match), so less by a factor of about 1.000. Merci

[image]

Comment: are your stats up to date ?

Comment: how could incorrect statistics explain it?

Comment: Estimates are arrived at from the top down, not from the bottom up.  So how the estimate came about is more dependent on your query, which you haven't shown us, than on child nodes in the plan.  Which estimate is closer to accurate?

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).